# preg_split for fields on a SQL query

Tags: php, regex

I need to separate fields on a `SQL` query like:

```
$fields="id, name, contact(name,surname) as full_name,age";
```

by using `preg_split("/\,/",$fields)` result is:

```
id
name
contact(name
surname)
age
```

I need to get this result:

```
id
name
contact(name,surname) as full_name
age
```

I know the trick is on the regular expression, which are always difficult for me. Could you please help me in the correct regexp?

Comment: are you writing the sql by your self ? if yes, add a space between **,** and **age** so you can search for **', '**

Comment: yeah, I pass the fields to a function that automatically splits then, execute the query and shows the table as HTML

Comment: Yep, you can add space between full_name and age and search by comma and a space /\,\s/

Comment: Isn't it `CONCAT` instead of `contact`?

Comment: sure, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Dwza solution does indeed work, a better regexp would be

```
/(?:,\s*)(?=(?:[^)]|\([^(]*\))*$)/
```

This regexp capture all of the commas, that may or may not have a space after and that are not inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

solution is

```
$fields="id, name, contact(name,surname) as full_name, age"; 
// space needed after the comma                       ^
```

than use

```
preg_split("/\,\s/",$fields)
```

Comment: yes, but in that case I need to correct all the previous calls (there are so many..its a company ERP). I want to modify the regular expression so as not to worry for previous or future calls